# G AppScript Search Files

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to write a script that will allow me to search within all of google drive, including shared teams and subfolders (Many Subfolders)

With what I wrote I can't find all the files, in fact there is a discrepancy between the ones I see from the web page and the ones the script returns to me

This is just a part of the script, when the file is found, it is moved to a folder. I have several files to move, via browser it is not manageable.

```
function SearchFiles() {
  //Please enter your search term in the place of Letter
  var searchFor ='title contains "find ME"';
  var names =[];
  //var fileIds=[];
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchFor);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    //var fileId = file.getId();// To get FileId of the file
    //fileIds.push(fileId);
    var name = file.getName();
    names.push(name);

  }

  for (var i=0;i<names.length;i++){
    Logger.log(names[i]);
    //Logger.log("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + fileIds[i]);

  }

}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot `This is just a part of the script, when the file is found, it is moved to a folder. I have several files to move, via browser it is not manageable.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: As written above, find all files that contain a given name and move them within a folder. Moving inside a folder is not present in the script entered above. The problem I have with the script is that I do not find all the files contained within my google drive via the script, but only some files. Whereas from the browser I see them all via the search

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. You want to search the files from all Drives including the shared Drive? Or, you want to move the files? Which one do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to search for files within my entire google drive, if I find files with a specific name, move them to a specific folder.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Comment: Yes, but doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### To find all files including the ones on Shared Drives, you need to use the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) instead of `DriveApp`

- As the documentation for [searchFiles(params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchfilesparams) specifies:

> Gets a collection of all files in the **user's Drive**

- On the contrary, the `Advanced Drive Service` based on the [Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api) allows you to set the parameters `supportsAllDrives` and `includeItemsFromAllDrives` to `true` and thus obtain results from all Drives
- To use the `Advanced Drive Service`, first you need to enable it following the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services)
- Then, you can use the method [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list) setting the [query parameter `q`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files) to `title contains 'find ME'`

In Apps Script it could look as following:

```js
function SearchFiles() {
  var searchFor ='title contains "findMe"';
  var files = Drive.Files.list({supportsAllDrives: true, includeItemsFromAllDrives: true, q: searchFor}).items;
  for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++){
    Logger.log(files[i].title);
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work; it can't find any files. `6:15:15 PM Notice Execution started
6:15:16 PM Notice Execution completed`

Comment: Just to double-check: Do you actually have files called "findMe"? Otherwise you have to modify the search string respectively.

Comment: Yes, i have it. The script ends after just a couple of seconds from when I run it.

Comment: This is what it looks like for me when I expand the execution logs after looking for a file with `var searchFor ='title contains "customDocName"'`: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pJxY_fX8Aw1AobcU0aU0lMqiJKgWVI-h/view?usp=sharing Sometimes Apps Script logs don"t show straightaway, so you might need to contract and expand or refresh the logs of an execution to see the entries. Try to look with another name where you know that a file with this name exists on your Drive. Maybe you only have files with the name `find ME`, but not `findMe`?

Comment: I have tried multiple file names present, always the same result

Comment: I am looking for files in the "shared drives" folders. Doing further testing, I only get results in case I search within "my drive".

Comment: Add `includeItemsFromAllDrives:true`  - see my updated answer.